# How to iterate for variable names in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm doing a project which has a lot of buttons. I would like to iterate over those buttons by its name. They are all named 'levelXbutton', where X can be a big number.

I'm now doing it with a lot of lines of code. But I'm sure there's a way to do it in a loop, specially in Kotlin.

For example, this is one of the operations I'd like to do:

```
if(FacadeData.getLastUnlockedLevel()<2){ binding.lvl2Button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)}
if(FacadeData.getLastUnlockedLevel()<3){ binding.lvl3Button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)}
if(FacadeData.getLastUnlockedLevel()<4){ binding.lvl4Button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)}
if(FacadeData.getLastUnlockedLevel()<5){ binding.lvl5Button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)}
```

Comment: Just store your buttons in a list of buttons.

Comment: Yes, that's a solution. But I should still introduce them all in a list at some point. Isn't there a way to iterate by their names?

Comment: You would need to use reflection, but you really, really, really shouldn't do that. Arrays and lists exist for that reason.

Comment: Okay, but how should I put them all in a list? If I want to have 100 buttons, should I put them in a list by hand?

Comment: Yes. For example using a loop. `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { buttonList.add(createButton()); }`

Comment: If they are all inside a ViewGroup layout you could iterate over the ViewGroup's children.

Comment: Yes. But I have 20 buttons on my xml which represents the view of my Fragment. Then I'd like to configure those buttons on my Fragment class, in its onCreateView method.

Comment: As @RobCo said, if your fragment has a buttonLayout containing all the buttons, then you can iterate through the children of buttonLayout

Comment: I need to iterate by its ID (which is "buttonX", where X is its number). They are not in order, and they wouldn't be in the ViewGroup. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @werepis12 my answer should do what you want

Comment: add your buttons dynamically (programmatically) to the layout and store them in a collection which you can then iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop to go through the buttons numbers and then load their ids with a string like so:

```
for (i in 0..20) {
    val layoutID = context.resources.getIdentifier("lvl${i}Button", "id", context.packageName)
    val button = findViewById(layoutID) as Button

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        applyChangeRecursively(findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)) {
            it.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }

    }

    fun getResourceName(view:View):String? {
        if (view.id > 0 && view is Button) {
            return view.resources.getResourceName(view.id)
        }
        return null
    }

    fun matchesLabel(resourceName:String?):Boolean = resourceName?.matches(Regex(".*lvl\\d+Button")) ?: false

    fun applyChange(v:View, u:(View)->Unit) = v.run(u)
    fun applyChangeRecursively(parent:View, fun1:(View)->Unit){
        when (parent) {
            is ViewGroup -> parent.children.forEach{ applyChangeRecursively(it, fun1) }
            else -> if(matchesLabel(getResourceName(parent))) { applyChange(parent, fun1) }
        }
    }

}
```